# JHipster's front-end sometimes doesn't auto-reload / respond to a refresh

Tags: jhipster

I'm running the basic "jhipster-sample-app" with Angular 5, and I'm using JHipster 5.5.0. I run the backend with `./mvnw` and front-end with `npm start`, and everything works correctly, with me making changes in the .html & .ts files, and the front-end refreshes correctly.

However, about 70% of the time, I will continue to make changes to the front-end files, but the site will stop auto-reloading. And then I'll click into a new link in the website (like "Administration - User management"), but it just loads forever. And I refresh the website but the site just loads forever.

I have ctrl+c the `npm start`, then `kill -9` the 'node' process (as ctrl+c'ing the `npm start` doesn't kill it, then `npm start` to get my changes to register. But again the whole thing only fails around 70% of the time. And other times I can continue to make changes and it works just fine. And some of the times it will work fine, but then after a minute or two of making changes it will then fail.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening? I didn't change anything major with the sample code.

Comment: Are you using a Node LTS version?

Comment: @JonRuddell i just switched to 10.13.0 and it seems to be working much better now